# Need to split info(,) in a column into two & change top left corner name... usual solutions not working

Tags: python, pandas, split, concatenation

[image: Here is my dataframe with pandas]

I want to split info in Cost_of_debt column. Not working :

```py
ICR[['Cost_of_debt', 'Ratings']] = ICR['Cost_of_debt'].str.split(',',1, expand=True).
```

Also not working is the:

```
DF.columns.name = None
```

to remove 'AMZN' in the top left corner.

If it can help, I used concat function to data frames for different tickers and I had previously used on DFAMZN.columns.name='AMZN' for example. The DF you see is derived from this one and is still carrying that value...

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: From the image it seems starting two columns are `index` you want to drop the index or reset index in the case if you don't want. Also add the error or output which you are getting for current splitting method. Don't upload images and add mock data too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(df.assign(**df['Cost_of_debt'].apply(pd.Series).set_axis(['Cost_of_debt', 'Ratings'],axis=1))
.rename_axis([None,None]))
```